# PHP regex match Latin words may contains symbols, digits and spaces

Tags: php, regex

There are names of records in which are mixed Cyrillic and Latin words, symbols, spaces, digits, etc.

I need to preg_match (PHP) only Latin part with any symbols in any combinations.

Test set:

```
БлаблаБла Uty-223
Блабла (бла.)Бла CAROP-C
Бла бла ST.MORITZ
Бла бла RAMIRO2-TED
LA PLYSGNE 1 H - 001
```

(Блабла) - doesn't matter Cyrillic words.

So i tried pattern:

```
/[-0-9a-zA-Z.]+/
```

But [Блабла (бла.)Бла CAROP-C] and [LA PLYSGNE 1 H - 001] not found as string.

Next i tried to write more flexible pattern:

```
/[-0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:.)?+(?:\s+)?+[-0-9a-zA-Z]+/
```

But there is still problem with matching [LA PLYSGNE 1 H - 001].

Is there any idea how can this be solved?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to match this? `[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:[.\h-]+[0-9a-zA-Z.]+)*`  https://regex101.com/r/2DP7Pg/1

Comment: Maybe you just want to remove all chars other than ASCII letters at the start of a string? `preg_replace('~^[^A-Za-z]+~u', '', $string)`? See https://regex101.com/r/kRuv0u/1

Comment: @The fourth bird - Yes, perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `.` and `-` can not occur at the beginning or end, you can start the match with `[0-9a-zA-Z]` and optionally repeat one of the chars listed in the character class followed by again `[0-9a-zA-Z]`

```
\b[0-9a-zA-Z]+(?:[.\h-]+[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*\b
```

- The `\b` is a word boundary preventing a partial word match
- `\h` matches a horizontal whitespace character

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/OT6j1U/1).

---

Matching at least a single char `[0-9a-zA-Z]` with allowed chars `.` and `-` in the whole string, and asserting whitespace boundaries to the left and right

```
(?<!\S)[.-]*\b[0-9a-zA-Z](?:[0-9a-zA-Z.\h-]*[0-9a-zA-Z.-])?(?!\S)
```

- Using `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` are lookaround assertions that are whitespace boundaries, asserting not a non whitespace char to the left and the right.

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/OIFjUV/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a *script run* starting with a latin letter:

```
~(*sr:\p{Latin}.*\S)~u
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/dfCNL#v8.2.1)

Comment: That is something new to me :-) I can find it here https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2syntax.html#SEC21 What exactly does it do?

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Basically, a script run succeeds when all the characters in the subpattern have the same *script extension* unicode property (*Latin* here) or are common characters. There's a better explanation here https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2unicode.html#scriptruns , and 2-3 examples in the txt version (that are probably somewhere in the html version).

Comment: @Thefourthbird: take a look also here https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr24/#Script_Extensions